# Dynamically add background images to multiple elements

Tags: jquery, css

I have a list of images I want to display. The images have different widths and heights , and I want to put them all into a li element, but the li element should have the same dimensions for each child image.

The only way to to this(so that images will fit in the the standard size li box) is to specify the image as a background of the li element:

```
<ul>
      <li>
        <div></div>
        <span>Image1</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div></div>
        <span>Image2</span>
      </li> 
      <li>
        <div></div>
        <span>Image3</span>
      </li> 
      <li>
        <div></div>
        <span>Image4</span>
      </li>   
    ...and many more  
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul li {       
        width: 75px;  
        height: 75px;
      }


ul li div{
        background-image: url('genereic path calculated in jquery');
        background-size: contain;  /*IMPORTANT THIS!*/
      }
```

All images should be resized to 75 by 75...So that the the images fits the box - That is why I am using background image property...

Basically, I can do this for each image, but I have a lot of images...So I will need to specify a background image for each list item child div...

How can I dynamically add this background image for each new li>div?

Example:

```
$(function() {

    $( "li div" ).each(function() {
      $(this).css('background-image','url(images/' + 'imagetitle)');
  });
});
```

How can I make this dymamic, without having to specify a background image for each div...

Thank you!

Comment: That will depend entirely on whether you have an array of image filenames, or whether they conform to a pattern like `image-01.jpg`, `image-02.jpg`, etc., or maybe you're obtaining them via AJAX....

Comment: @Blazemonger : i also agree with blaze either you have a array or a sequence of images in a folder like img01.jpg,img02.jpg... and so on .

Answer (score 0):

First, you will have any data source containing your images, right? Create an array from it.

```
var liArray = { 'url1', 'url2', 'url3' };
```

Then try the for-loop

```
for(i=0, i<liArray.length,i=i+1)
{
var odv = $.create("li");
odv.css('background-image','url(images/' + liArray[i])');
odv.appendTo($(ul));
}
```

This will create your images dynamically. Was this your question?

You have to take care about your absolute image path. I think it's clear that within brackets there is no images folder needed if you pass absolute urls within the array.

Comment: maybe you will need to select your odv-variable with an $(odv) statement. I'm unsure right now, if it is still a variable in JQ context. Just try - if you have any Problems just post them.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would put the CSS in a CSS file.

```
.addBackground {
   background: url(./path_to_my_image.png);
}
```

Then, as you are using jQuery anyway..

```
$("span").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass("addBackground");
});
```

Comment: thanks. But how do I dynamically populate the paths for the images? This way, I will have to specify different .addbackground classes...each image will have a diff background

Comment: Are you attempting to create say an image gallery using an un-ordered list with each list items > div as the thumbnail? Basically I think you can hard code the CSS file and apply the styles at DOM ready tweaking the above code, or use a server side language like PHP to index all the files in your images folder and spit out the CSS file, that way each time you add to the directory a file it will create a new class. I can provide some code if you think this sounds a good way to go.

Comment: YEs exactly. The li item should contain both the div(thumbnail) and the span(which is the text as an image description)...I would appreciate your help yes

Answer (score 0):

**PHP code:**

```
<?php


function createGallery() {
if ($pwd = opendir('./images/')) {

    /* Loop over the directory. */
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($pwd))) {
        $file_name = pathinfo($file);
        $fn = $file_name['filename'];

            if ($file_name['extension'] == "png") {

                doCSS($fn, $file);

            }

    }
    closedir($pwd);
}
}

function doCSS($fn, $image) {
$cssFile = "./gallery.css";

if (file_exists($cssFile)) {
    // Attempt to open for append
    $fh = fopen($cssFile, "a") or die("Error opening file.");
} else {
    // Attempt to create
    $fh = fopen($cssFile, "w") or die("Error opening file.");
}

        $string = "#".$fn." { background: url(./images/".$image."); } ";
    // Write to file
    fwrite($fh, $string);


fclose($fh);    
}

createGallery();

?>
```

**Outputs into gallery.css**

```
#photo1 { background: url(./images/photo1.png); } #photo3 { background: url(./images/photo3.png); } #photo3menu_OLD { background: url(./images/photo3menu_OLD.png); } #photo1small { background: url(./images/photo1small.png); } #photo3menu { background: url(./images/photo3menu.png); } #photo3small { background: url(./images/photo3small.png); } #photo4 { background: url(./images/photo4.png); } #photo4details { background: url(./images/photo4details.png); }
```

Personally I would write a class for positioning the divs and fixing dimensions and include that in your main page CSS file something along the lines of: -

```
.dimensions {
    position: relative;
    width: 75px; height: 75px; display: block;
}
```

I would also use PHP to create the markup on the page too rather than JS as you are iterating through the directory anyway to create the CSS file. Hope this helps.